# Easy way to extract Unit Test case from bowels of Java application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

Sometimes I'm stepping with the debugger through the guts of an application trying to track down some weird behavior... when there's an *aha moment* when I realize that some method is not properly handling a totally valid use-case, but also that I don't have a decent Unit Test to reproduce this scenario.

The logical next thing to do is to create the Unit Test. IDE wizards give you a nice empty template that wraps around a target class of your choice. Then you hunt down all the dependencies of the method and figure out whether to instantiate or mock those dependencies, construct objects for all the input parameters, etc. A lot of tedious, error-prone work.

After doing this a few times you realize the work is very mechanical. All the information - dependencies, values, etc, are available in the code or in the current stack frame of the debugger at that breakpoint.

Is there a way (a programming technique, which might be packaged in a tool) to automatically generate a Unit Test based on what the debugger already knows?